# Using packages wrapfig and fulpage at the same time dont work

Tags: wrapfigure, wrapfig, fullpage

When i use the packages
`\usepackage{wrapfig}` and `\usepackage{fullpage}` it leaves a whites space where there is no text under the image.

I tried deleting other packeages but when i delete the fullpage package the problem is solved, but then the pages are not as wide as i want them to be.

[image: with fullpage package]
[image: without fullpage package]

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %voor accenten op letters ( umlaut bijv.)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %For better font
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{gensymb} %  Generic symbols for both text and math mode
\usepackage{hyperref} % voor het toevoegen van links aan het document
\usepackage{graphicx} % voor plaatjes in het document
\usepackage{tabularx} % Tabulars with adjustable-width columns
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Extensive control of page headers and footers in LaTeX2e
\usepackage{lastpage} % Needed for extra-fancy page numbering
\usepackage{pdfpages} % Include PDF documents in LaTeX
\usepackage{eurosym} %(geen idee of het nodig is) voor het 'euro'-%teken
\usepackage{wrapfig} %  Produces figures which text can flow around
\usepackage{tocloft} %  Control table of contents, figures, etc
\usepackage{textgreek} %voor textomega enzo
\begin{document}


\subsection{Literatuuronderzoek Glycerine}
Aangezien er tijdens dit verslag veel met Glycerine gewerkt en berekend wordt is het handig om wat informatie over Glycerine te weten. Daarom staat hieronder wat informatie over Glycerine wat handig is om te weten voor dit verslag. 

De viscositeit van Glycerine verandert heel veel naarmate met de temperatuur, dit komt doordat het een amorfe stof is. In afbeelding \ref{tab:viscositeit Glycerine} is de viscositeit van Glycerine te zien bij verschillende temperaturen en verhoudingen. Omdat de leidingen in de fabriek liggen en het nooit kouder dan 10 graden in de fabriek is en de verhouding van de gebruikte Glycerine 99.7\% is wordt er een viscositeit van 3900 cp gehanteerd. Behalve bij de berekeningen van de huidige situatie daar wordt de temperatuur gehanteerd die op dat moment gemeten is en dus ook de viscositeit die daar bij hoort.
%referentie toevoegen voor de gebruikte afbeelding

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
\caption{Viscositeit Glycerine bij temperatuur en verhouding\cite{Glycerine_an_overview}\label{wrap-fig:1}}
\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{smeltpunt glycerine.png}
\end{wrapfigure} 
Het vries punt van Glycerine veranderd ook enorm met de verhouding. Zoals te zien in afbeelding \ref{wrap-fig:1} zou een 99.5 procent Glycerine verhouding al bij ongeveer 17 graden bevriezen. Na dit zelf getest te hebben blijkt dit dus niet helemaal het geval te zijn. Dit komt doordat dit punt niet het vries punt is maar het smeltpunt. Dit betekent dus niet per se dat het een vaste stof wordt. Pure Glycerine wordt zelden gezien in zijn gekristalliseerde vorm. Dit komt dus doordat Glycerine dus een amorfe stof is. Hierdoor heeft het een glas overgang. Dit betekent dat in plaats van dat de stof vast wordt de viscositeit enorm hoger wordt. Bij een temperatuur van -80° Celsius is de viscositeit zo hoog dat het als een vast stof beschouwd kan worden. 


\subsubsection{Opslaan van Glycerine}
Bij het opslaan van Glycerine komt ook het een en ander bij kijken. Glycerine is in principe een natuurlijke grondstof, echter is het niet iets wat zomaar in de grond gevonden wordt. Ook aangezien het dus een natuurlijke grondstof heeft het een houdbaarheids datum. Om te voorkomen dat de Glycerine over datum gaat moet de opslag voldoen aan bepaalde richtlijnen en wetgeving. \\

\begin{itemize}
    \item Wetgeving\\
    Alle Glycerine moet opgevangen worden bij lekkage. Bij onze huidige tanks wordt dit gedaan door een dubbelwandige tank. 

    Voor ondergrondse tanks is er een andere regelgeving. Zo moet de tank vloeistofdicht zijn oftewel kathodische bescherming. Dit is volgens PGS 28 en Barim. Ook moet er een peilbus zitten om het monsters te nemen van het grondwater.
    
    \item Eisen en advies leverancier \\
    Zij hebben het volgende aangegeven over het opslaan van Glycerine.
    Zij adviseren het gebruik van rvs-tanks. Aan de hand van hoe sterk onze pompen zijn wordt het aangeraden om de tanken op zijn minst te isoleren en afhankelijk van het proces zouden de tanks ook verwarmd kunnen zijn. Om de viscositeit van de Glycerine laag te houden. 

    \item Regelgeving vanuit \\
    Vanuit kwaliteitsoogpunt moet het volgende in acht worden genomen omdat de vloeistof bestaat uit een Foodgrade Glycerine met een zuiverheid van 99,7%
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item De tank dient schoon opgeleverd te worden voor gebruik.
        \item De tank dient aan de binnenkant voorzien te worden van een laag die voorkomt dat het tankmateriaal oplost in de Glycerine. Dit geldt ook voor de appendages, leidingen, kranen etc.\\
        Dit kan gedaan worden door middel van een coating te doen, echter is dit bij RVS 316 niet nodig aangezien dit al foodgrade is. Bij leiding werk is RVS 304 ook voldoende.
        De beschermings laag kan bijvoorbeeld een kathodische bescherming zijn. 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: make an example that other people can actually test. Replace references to local image by example-image. And remove irrelevant packages.

Comment: this is unrelated to `fullpage`, `wrapfig` is document as not working next to a list. We can't use your example, but you can probably use the optional argument to specify the nmber of line to cut in for the wrapped figure

Comment: Also, wrapfig treats the section title as if it were only `\baselineskip` in size.